# ng-click doesn't work with external JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click, algolia

I am creating an ionic project and I am trying to integrate with Algolia autocomplete.js. I managed to make the search system work, however I added a ng-click on my search results and this function is not working as presented in this codepen that I did as example below:

http://codepen.io/marcos_arata/pen/VKVOky

Inside my algolia's result template:

```
<a ng-click="add_name({{{ name }}})">
```

Function that should be run when clicked:

```
$scope.add_name = function(name) {
    alert('User added!');
    console.log(name);
}
```

I tried to inject the results inside the scope but didn't work as well:

```
autocomplete('#search_name', { hint: false, debug: true, openOnFocus: true },[{
    source: index.ttAdapter({ hitsPerPage: 15 }),
    templates: {
        header: '',
        suggestion: function(hit) {

            $scope.hit = hit;

            return template.render(hit);

        }
    }
}]);
```

http://codepen.io/marcos_arata/pen/VKVOky

---- SOLVED ----

Instead of creating a ng-click function inside your templates, you can handle the event click of your search inside your "autocomplete:selected" function and use the dataset and suggestion results.

```
.on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {

  $scope.name = suggestion.name;
  console.log($scope.name);
  ## create any functions with the suggestion and dataset results inside

});
```

Comment: You can do like this : <a ng-click="add_name(name)">

Comment: hi @VijayMaheriya, doesn't work as well. my function doesn't work when I click on my search results as you can check on my codepen

Comment: the click is being swallowed by the `.on('autocomplete:selected'` event.  I don't know why that is or how to fix it, but I thought maybe that extra info might be helpful.

Comment: angular and javascript both are not working. coz it is stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITING THE ANSWER:

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKqQkr):

Apparently the suggestion keep the name clicked, so you dont need an extra function:

```
.on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {

  $scope.name = suggestion.name;
  console.log($scope.name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine! The only issue is that it looks like the 'function' is running 2 times. Do you know why?

Comment: I will try to open the codepen and check it out in a bit

Comment: also, do you know how can I clear the input after the selection? I tried with angular.element(document.querySelector('#search_location')).html(''); but didn't work